# Get groups(only allowed) for user using single mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Recently i came across one interesting problem. Let add some tables namely User, Group and their Join table User_Group. Following is the dummy representation of the tables

User

```
user_id | user_name 
  1     |  a
  2     |  b
  3     |  c
```

Group

```
group_id | group_code
  1      |  G1
  2      |  G2
  3      |  G3
```

User_Group

```
userid  | groupid | exclusion
  1     |   1     |  0
  1     |   2     |  0
  2     |   1     |  1
```

Well the problem is to get the list of groups for the user on which he have access on. 
General assumption of the user access in the group is :

- If user have no entry in User_group join table the user has access on
  all groups (ie. G1, G2 and G3)
- If user have entry in User_Group with
  exclusion 0 then that user have access in that group only (user 1 has
  access in G1 and g2)
- If user have entry in User_Group with exclusion
  1 then that user have no access in that group but he has access in
  other all other groups(user 2 is denied only on g1 and should have
  access in G2 and G3)

Here's the query that get me results for case 1 & 3 but fails for case 2.

```
SELECT g.id, g.code, ug.user_groups_id, ug.exclusion FROM group g
LEFT JOIN user_group ug ON ug.group_id = g.id 
     AND ug.user_id = 1 -- works for user 2 and 3 but fails for user 1         
WHERE (ug.exclusion = 0 OR ug.exclusion IS NULL)
```

Please suggest if we can get the list of groups using just single query

Comment: Get rid of the IS NULL bit and change WHERE to AND. And note that `group` is a reserved word so you may want to rethink that (or tell us the truth ;-) ).

Comment: So, how do you want to show the groups that user has access to? In one field? For example userID 3 'Group 1, Group 2 and Group 3' as one field?

Comment: @Edper just want them in the rows (3, G1)(3,G2),(3,G3)

Comment: @SureshMaharjan, so for user 1 you want to receive 2 groups, but you're receiveing one, right ??

Comment: @strawberry ... this is just the over simplified example of the real problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem.

You can solve this by generating a list of all users and all groups (using `cross join`).  Then use `left join` to match back to the list of groups that are known.  The logic is then:

1. Case 1 is to use all the groups when there is no match.
2. Case 2 is to use only the groups that do match.
3. Case 3 is to use only the groups that do not match.

Here is the query:

```
select u.userid,
       (case when max(ug.exclusion) is null  -- all groups
             then group_concat(g.groupcode)
             when max(ug.exclusion) = 0   -- only those included
             then group_concat(case when ug.groupid is not null then g.groupcode end)
             when max(ug.exclusion) = 1   -- exclude these
             then group_concat(case when ug.groupid is null then g.groupcode end)
        end)
from users u cross join
     groups g left join
     user_groups ug
     on u.userid = ug.userid and g.groupid = ug.groupid 
group by u.userid;
```

Do note that this only uses the exclusion flag in the aggregate -- basically assuming that it is the same on all rows in `user_groups`.  In fact, this flag could go at the `user` level rather than at the `user_groups` level.  This assumption is consistent both with the sample data and the explanation of the problem.

Comment: in the query above you're cross joining groups and why you are again joining groups again at the end?

Comment: @SureshMaharjan . . . That was a mistake on my part (it was left in from an earlier incarnation of the logic).

Comment: this solves one problem of (groups for user) and i was thinking similar for (users for group) but it was not as the exclusion  field did not work on the group level. Any solution for that problem too ...

Comment: @Hakucha . . . I think you should ask that as another question.  This question is about getting the groups that a user is in.

Comment: ...This is the one that i was asking  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870956/get-users-in-group-in-single-mysql-query