# Get users(only allowed) in group in single mysql Query

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

From following tables i have to fetch the list of users allowed in the specified group upon the basis of following logic.

- Case 1 : all users qualifies when there is no match (no record in
  user_group table).
- Case 2 : Users in group that do match (having
  exclusion = 0) in user_group table
- Case 3 : Users in group other than
  denied (having exclusion =1)

**MyUser**

```
user_id | user_name 
  1     |  a
  2     |  b
  3     |  c
```

**MyGroup**

```
group_id | group_code
  1      |  G1
  2      |  G2
  3      |  G3
```

**User_Group**

```
userid  | groupid | exclusion
  1     |   1     |  0
  1     |   2     |  0
  2     |   1     |  1
```

Here's the query that works for case 1 & 3 but fails for case 2.

```
SELECT u.id, g.id, g.code, ug.exclusion FROM MyUser u
join MyGroup g 
LEFT JOIN user_group ug ON ug.group_id = g.id 
     AND ug.user_id = 1 -- works for user 2 and 3 but fails for user 1         
WHERE (ug.exclusion <> 0 OR ug.exclusion IS NULL)
```

So, in the case of record with exclusion  = 1 then that record gets and other groups are added with the null condition. And the problem is the null fields also gets added for exclusion = 0 which is not required at all.

Please suggest if we can get the list of users for given group using just single query

Expected Result :

```
g1(a,c), g2(a,b,c), g3(b,c)
```

Comment: @strawberry ... User a is only allowed in group 1 & 2 that's why it's not allowed in group 3

Answer (score 0):

This should work, or something close to it.

```
select u.user_id, g.group_id, g.code
from MyGroup g
    cross join users u 
    left join user_group allowed ON u.user_id = allowed.user_id AND g.group_id = allowed.group_id AND allowed.exclusion = 0
    left join user_group allowbydefault ON u.user_id = allowbydefault.user_id
where (allowed.user_id is not null OR allowbydefault.group_id is null)
-- and g.group_id = 1 -- uncomment to get everyone authorized for group #1
-- and u.user_id = 35 -- uncomment to get every group that user #35 is authorized for
group by u.user_id, g.group_id, g.code
```

I used SQL Server to test this but this should at least give you another point of attack for MySQL.

Comment: g1(a,c), g2(a,b,c), g3(b,c) this is the expected users (inside bracket) for three groups but the query does not fetch these result :(

Comment: This probably isn't the most efficient way, but I changed the 2nd left join to key off user id's instead of group id's:
`left join user_group allowbydefault ON u.user_id = allowbydefault.user_id`

instead of:
`left join user_group allowbydefault ON g.group_id = allowbydefault.group_id`

This will give a user all permissions if that user isn't in the permissions table.